# Conditional re-sizes with carrierwave, depending on polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, polymorphic-associations

I have the folowing three models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :as => :imageable
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

My image controller looks like this:

```
class Admin::ImagesController < AdminController
  before_filter :find_imageable

  def new
    @image = @imageable.images.new
  end

  def create
    if @image = @imageable.images.create(params[:image])
      redirect_to admin_images_path(:imageable_type => @imageable.class, :imageable_id => @imageable.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def find_imageable
    klass = params[:imageable_type].capitalize.constantize
    @imageable = klass.find(params[:imageable_id])
  end
end
```

Everything is working as expected, but now I want to resize the images depending on the type on the type of assosiation:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  version :thumb, :if => :is_product? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  protected
  def is_product? image
    model.imageable.class == 'Product' # => imageable is nil!
  end
end
```

The problem is, 'model' does not have the association with the imageable in the uploader. When I inspect the model, this is what it looks like:

```
#<Image id: nil, name: "test", image: nil, imageable_id: nil, imageable_type: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I did find a [workaround](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/530), but I'm still wondering if there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I will usualy do this

```
  version :thumb, :if => :thumb_version_enabled? do
    process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]
  end

  version :big, :if => :big_version_enabled? do
    process :resize_to_fill => [600,600]
  end

  def include_version?(v)
    if self.model.respond_to?("only_versions")
      self.model.only_versions.collect(&:to_s).include? v.to_s
    else
      true
    end
  end

  protected 

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    return super unless /^(.*)_version_enabled(=?)/ =~ method_name
    return include_version?(method_name.to_s.gsub("_version_enabled?","").gsub("_version_enabled",""))
  end
```

in the target model (where uploader is mounted) i will define a method to define the versions enabled

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  ##....omiss
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def self.only_versions
    [:thumb, :big, :small, :original]
  end

  def only_versions
    self.class.only_versions
  end
end
```

in case of polymorphic association you could delegate the method to associated model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :data, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

  def only_versions
    if self.imageable && self.imageable.respond_to?("only_versions")
      self.imageable.only_versions
    else
      ImageUploader.versions.keys
    end
  end
```

if the method "only_versions" is missing, all versions in enabled by default ...